# reading data into .ejs from a CSV in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am extracting data from a CSV using d3.csv and routing it into a ejs.

```
d3.csv("http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/assig2/data1.csv", function(data) {
  var data1 = data;
  console.log(data1[0]);

  app.get('/doctor', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) { 
        res.render('doctor.ejs', {
            user : req.user,
            datap1 : data1
        });
    });
});
```

The console shows the correct output.
In the ejs, I am calling the same by

```
<%= datap1[0]%>
```

and it shows [object object]
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess console.log converts passed object to a string. Similarly you can use e.g.: datap1: JSON.stringify(data1).

Comment: didn't work. shows nothing...

Comment: To answer your question: [object object] means that on your object .toString() was called and this is it's output. Since you object doesn't overrid .toString() default Object.prototype.toString() was called. Ejs just rendered that what you provided. You should override toString() or better in your case convert properly data to e.g. string before passing to ejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the client end you can parse the string back to an object using JSON.parse()

and while sending it as a string from the server side

```
app.get('/doctor', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) { 
        res.render('doctor.ejs', {
            user : req.user,
            datap1 :  JSON.stringify(data1)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: did you **console.log( <%= datap1%>);** in your ejs code... I want to see the ejs too

Comment: If you will use above code then you need to put in ejs <%= datap1 %> no [0].